# How to get all active Tax rules

Tags: tax, rules

I have added tax rule in

```
sales -> manage tax rules
```

and associate with customer tax class.

Now how can I programatically get this rules or fetch all the rules defined here ?

I tried this

```
$tax = Mage::getModel('tax/calculation')->getCollection();

            foreach($tax as $rr) {
                 echo $rr->getRuleName();
                 echo $rr->getRuleId();
                 echo '<br>';
            }
```

but getting blank

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('tax/calculation_rule')->getCollection();
if($collection->getSize()) {
    $collection->addCustomerTaxClassesToResult()
    ->addProductTaxClassesToResult()
    ->addRatesToResult();
}
if($collection->getSize()) {
    foreach($collection as $rule) {
        print_r($rule);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load by id:

```
$taxRule = Mage::getModel('tax/sales_order_tax')->load($id);
```

or get all:

```
$taxRules = Mage::getModel('tax/sales_order_tax')->getCollection();

foreach($taxRules as $taxRule){
    echo $taxRule->getId();
//etc
}
```